# Issue with FTP-Sync, using command "ftp-sync:init" I get error message: "Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Tags: visual-studio-code, ftp, vscode-extensions

I have downloaded vs code to my mac and am trying to connect to the server using the ftp-sync extension built into vs code. After installing ftp-sync, I tried to use the command ftp:sync-init and the following error appears:

> "Command 'Ftp-sync: Init' resulted in an error (Cannot read property '0' of undefined)".

I'm a beginner at using VS Code and don't know how to fix the problem and need to get my server going asaap to access files.

Comment: @KenWhite I have tried to search for the same error message but have not seen the same issue. I am using a mac and most problems are using microsoft. My problem does not include code, it is an issue I am having when trying to open the json file.

Answer (score 2):

You have to first open a folder either empty o or an existing project so the .vscode can be created.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).